# Series containing Combinations

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

The probability mass function of a random variable X is given by
$P(X=x)=k*\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\quad , x=0,1,2....n\quad$
Where k is a constant .The moment generating function is $ M_{x} t$ is.

I know that we should find $\sum_{x=0}^{n} k * \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$ and equate it to $1$ to get the value of k
But how do we solve the series.

Comment: [Sum of the binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Sums_of_the_binomial_coefficients) is the number of ways to choose a subset of any size from a collection of $n$ objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{x=o}^{n} \frac {n!}{x!(n-x)!} = \sum\limits_{x=o}^{n}  \binom {n} {x}=(1+1)^{n}$ by Binomial Theorem. Hence $(k) (2^{n})=1$  and $k=\frac 1  {2^{n}}$.

Use the same theorem to show that $M_X(t)=((1+e^{t}) )/2)^{n}$.